# Manipulando ListView C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, listview, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho uma ListView que exibe os dados na tela e possui várias linhas e colunas.
Por exemplo:

```
      Cl1 | Cl2 | Cl3
  L1  aa  | bb   |  cc
  L2  ab  | bc   |  cd
  L3  ac  | bd   |  ce
```

Gostaria de saber, se tem alguma função nativa do c# (tipo: lambda, LINQ, etc), para pesquisar e alterar os valores no ListView? Por exemplo: Pesquisar por 'ab' (Cl1,L2), e alterar 'cd' (Cl3, L2) para 'teste'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em teoria você pode extrair [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e iterá-la como uma lista:

```
var lista = minhaListView.Items;
```

Aí você pode pesquisar assim:

```
var elemento = lista.FirstOrDefault(l => l.nome == "Fulano");
```

Alterando:

```
elemento.nome = "Beltrano";
```

Ou então pra acessar uma determinada linha (considere que para a lista a posição 0 é o primeiro elemento):

```
var elementoNaTerceiraLinha = minhaListView.Items[2];
```

Comment: Mas, como eu irei saber, qual é a linha correspondente do ListView, que esta em `elemento`?
Pois, nesta variável você pegou somente uma instância da `minhaListView`.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno Atualizei a resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Foi de grande utilidade.